# Is there a PC equivalent for the Android 'Wifi Analyzer' App?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, android

I'm using the Wifi Analyzer app on my phone a lot at the moment as I need to set up and test some wireless networks. For people unfamiliar with the app, i've posted some screenshots of the app that I found on the internet.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm looking for some software that will do the same or similar thing, but on a PC. I've looked on Google, but could not find anything of use.

Comment: This belongs on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: [Acrylic WiFi Free](https://www.acrylicwifi.com/en/wlan-software/wlan-scanner-acrylic-wifi-free/)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

there's a few - [inSSIDer](http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider) is what i prefer - <strike>though i often use [meraki's wifi stumber](http://tools.meraki.com/stumbler) at client's systems</strike> wifi stumbler seems to have been EOLed - something about it written in java IIRC.

For linux [linssd is a very similar application](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linssid/) that seems to work alright

Comment: +1 Perfect! That's exactly the type of thing I wanted. Thanks

Comment: inSSIDer is very nice cause it has that channel/signal strength graph, same as WiFi Analyzer :)

Comment: Since Wifi Analyzer is _free_, it could be important for some, that you need to pay for inSSIDer. While basic price of 20 USD is acceptable, price of 250 USD for Office edition, which actually includes all, that you'll find in _free_ Wifi Analyzer, is an overkill.

Comment: At the time I posted the answer inSSIDer was free, and I had wifi stumbler as a second choice. As you can see, things like this change, which is why we arn't fond of software recs here any more

Comment: Just found WiFi Analyser on the Windows App store which sounds like exactly what you were looking for back in 2011 and exactly what I needed right now for Windows 10. https://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/store/p/wifi-analyzer/9nblggh33n0n

Answer (score 8):

Also useful is [Xirrus' wifi inspector](http://xirrus.com/library/wifitools.php):

> The Xirrus Wi-Fi Inspector is a powerful tool for managing and
>   troubleshooting the Wi-Fi on a Windows XP SP2 or later, Vista, or 7
>   laptop. Built in tests enable you to characterize the integrity and
>   performance of your Wi-Fi connection.
>
> Application includes:
>
> - Searching for Wi-Fi networks
> - Managing and troubleshooting Wi-Fi connections
> - Verifying Wi-Fi coverage
> - Locating Wi-Fi devices
> - Detecting rogue APs

Comment: Worth noting, that there is no direct download link. You're forced to provide extensive set of your personal data (from name and e-mail to such strange -- as for downloading this tool -- like your company name, size or industry it fits in). For me, out of question, if I have to share so much data to simply test a simple tool!

Comment: I just used dummy details and got access to the download no problem :)